# Extracting latitude andlongitude from javascript and passing to html form

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following problem

I use a google map inside an html form where the user can enter an address (autocomplete) and the marker goes to the place. The marker is draggable.

What I want is to extract latitude and longitude and pass the values to two different input text

i'm following this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

**Java Script**

```
<script>
    function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    }
</script>
```

this code is work well, now i want to extract the latitude and longitude and show them in input text inside a html form

```
input name="input_latitude" id="input_latitude" value=""
input name="input_longitude" id="input_longitude" value=""
```

i've tried like this but didnt work, because i dont know how to place this

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'dragend', function ( event ) {
        document.getElementById( "input_latitude" ).value = this.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById( "input_longitude" ).value = this.getPosition().lng();
    } );
```

can anyone help me? thankyou..

Comment: the id is `input_latitude` i'm sorry i have changed the question @JaromandaX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by extracting the data of geometry.location lat and lng property and print it as values to corresponding input text.

```
var loc = place.geometry.location;
var templat = loc.lat();
var templng = loc.lng();

document.getElementById("lat").value = templat;
document.getElementById("lng").value = templng;
```

Here's a working JSdiffle: http://jsbin.com/dawutes/

I've also added code snippet below:

```js
 function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

         var lat = document.getElementById('lat');
         var lng = document.getElementById('lng');
        
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
                                                       
            var loc = place.geometry.location;
            var templat = loc.lat();
            var templng = loc.lng();
           
            document.getElementById("lat").value = templat;
            document.getElementById("lng").value = templng;
          

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);

          
        });
      }
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<input id="lat" type="text" placeholder="Latitude">
<input id="lng" type="text" placeholder="Longitude">
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0wB2s8fFD1L9BBEWRKidcH31nrBZ4r0c&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'dragend', function ( event ) {
    document.getElementById( "input_latitude" ).value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById( "input_longitude" ).value = event.latLng.lng();
} );
```